# Using references as keys in AVL tree

Tags: c++, reference, avl-tree

I implemented an AVL tree and I am using references to objects as the keys.
However, I encountered a huge bug. 
Every time I am rebalancing the tree because I am using references, they change the values of the objects when I re-organize the tree.

Is there a way to surpass that?

Thank you.

Comment: Use std::reference_wrapper. Or use pointers, not references.

Comment: how will it help with the problem that we are running over data when we are fixing the tree?

Comment: please give a [mcve]